# Update derived persistence.xml in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to make my first web application on Spring+GWT and I use Maven plugin for Eclipse to build it.

persistence.xml file lies in src/main/resources/META-INF, but there is also a derived file persistence.xml in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF.

The latter is obviously used to create the persistence.xml in target directory, but i can't find out how to update this file - it stays as it is after I edit persistence.xml in /resources/META-INF, clean the project and recompile, it's not created anew if it was deleted and the build won't deploy after it is edited directly (no changes done that could possibly prevent deployment by themselves).

I feel there should be a simple answer, but googling around didn't help.

Comment: The target directory will be updated just like mentioned above (clean the project and recompile). If you try to edit it manually you will lose the changes when it is recompile. One suggestion it would be that when you made your changes it didn't compile properly hence it didn't generate the target directory.

Comment: The thing is, the target directory is generated, but for its creation the derived persistence.xml is used (unchanged) and not the original one that was edited. Looks like things reached an impasse..